# I need to show all user's data with how many days ago they inserted it into the database?

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am trying to get a Date Count using Carbon. Like 20 days ago created.
I want to send data in JSON format API.

I want to send it from the controller. Here is my Controller Code.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

public function index()
    
    {
        $now = Carbon::now();
        $users = User::all('first_name', 'last_name', 'profile_img', 'created_at');
        $date = $users->created_at->diffInDays($now);  
        return response()->json(['data' => $users , 'date' => $date]);
    }
```

But I get the error from the postman
[image]

Without the Date count, I can get all data without any error. So My problem is in here just. **Please inform me where is I am wrong.** Thank You

Comment: Hint: `$users` is a **list**... Which user do you want to get the created date for?

Comment: yea, Users are all list of total users. I need created_at total day count from today.
I do not want to search. I need all users data with how many days ago they inserted info.

Comment: I need to show all user's data with how many days ago they inserted it into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it using **model accessor** laravel. In `User` Model I am creating a function

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($created_at)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($created_at)->diffInDays(now());
    }
```

and In `Controller`, I have used this code.

```
public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all('first_name', 'last_name', 'profile_img', 'created_at');
        return response()->json(['data' => $users], 200);
    }
```

And now IT sends a fine result
[image]

Thank's all.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you're trying to get data from a collection of objects. it might be pluck or you may use a for each loop here to modify your data. like as -

```
$date = array();

foreach($users as $user){
 $date[] = $user->created_at->diffInDays($now); // or $user->created_at->diffForHumans();
}
```

for API you may use resource or Laravel Repository Pattern.

Comment: Thank you. As if I want to send data in JSON format. Can I do using a model accessor?

Comment: you have to send ready-made data to JSON response. You have to use that accessor before sending a response. the client won't able to access your model accessor or whatever you use, which you can access from your view file or on others. It's better to use a pattern or resources to modify.

Answer (score 0):

you can also format date in different format like this via model accessor

```
protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
    {
        return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
```